# Part sans serif font

Tags: fonts

I am using `titlesec` to change the font of `chapter` `section` etc. to Helvetica. I am struggling to do the same with `part`

This is the code I am using for `chapter` and `section`:

```
\titleformat{\chapter}
    {\normalfont\sffamily\huge\bfseries}
    {\thechapter. }{0em}{\setstretch{1}}
 \titleformat{\section}
    {\normalfont\sffamily\large\bfseries}
    {\thesection}{1em}{}
```

How do I set a `\titleformat` to mimic the standard look provded by the `book` class?

I only need to change the font to `\normalfont\sffamily`

Here is how it looks now:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the `display` format (Sec. 3 of the `titlesec` documentation). Looking into `book.cls` you see that the label "Part" is typeset in `\huge`, while the part's title comes in `\Huge`.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\part}[display]
    {\centering\normalfont\sffamily\huge\bfseries}
    {\partname~\Roman{part}}{2ex}{\Huge}

\begin{document}

\part{Blah}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for guiding me through the solution. Now I know how to reverse engineer the book class

Answer (score 3):

You can patch the relevant commands to use `\sffamily`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\xpatchcmd{\@part}{\normalfont}{\normalfont\sffamily}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\@spart}{\normalfont}{\normalfont\sffamily}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\part{Title}

This is the following text

\part*{Title}

\end{document}
```

Comment: what is ``spart`` for? Was that supposed to be ``chapter``?

Comment: @user1736049 It is `\@spart`, which is the internal command used when `\part*` is processed.